# If I use EXT4 driver for EXT3 filesystem, will I get better performance? Why?

Tags: kernel, filesystem, ext4, ext3

In my testing, I can see using EXT4 driver for EXT3 filesystem improve performance but I am not sure why.

Comment: What kind of driver are you talking about? How did you change those? If you mount an EXT3 file system as an ext4 performance will indeed slightly improve as you can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4

Comment: The Linux kernel mounts ext3 file systems using the ext4 driver by default these days.

Answer (score 2):

No, the ext4 driver mounts ext3 file systems using ext3 features only and performance is not affected.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339449/mounting-ext3-file-system-using-the-ext4-subsystem-what-does-this-mean-exact for details including

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c290ea01abb7907fde602f3ba55905ef10a37477

> The functionality of ext3 is fully supported by ext4 driver. Major distributions (SUSE, RedHat) already use ext4 driver to handle ext3 filesystems for quite some time.

Comment: ext4 is backward-compatible with ext3 and ext2, making it possible to mount ext3 and ext2 as ext4. This will slightly improve performance, because certain new features of ext4 can also be used with ext3 and ext2, such as the new block allocation algorithm. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4

ext4 is backward-compatible with ext3 and ext2, making it possible to mount ext3 and ext2 as ext4. This will slightly improve performance, because certain new features of ext4 can also be used with ext3 and ext2, such as the new block allocation algorithm.